# Linux ReadOnly Variable is not working - -bash: TMOUT: readonly variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have enabled readonly variable, so that other users does not modifify

But I am getting below message for every login, not sure it is error or error. How do confirm it is working?

```
-bash: TMOUT: readonly variable
```

I have added below entry in /etc/profile

```
TMOUT=900
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
```

OS: ubuntu 18

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue.  From your description, this could happen if `/etc/profile` has been sourced twice by your bash process. Run a new bash login shell with `-x` turned on, and analyze the output.

Comment: @user1934428, default bash profile (on multiple distros) sources /etc/profile, THEN loads the user's profile.  Most likely this is caused by an entry in the user's profile.

Comment: @Jeter-work : Which file are you refering to exactly, when you say _**default** bash profile_?

Comment: You are aware that `TMOUT` is a system variable used by Bash itself, and thus exported to all scripts? It controls the timeout for the `read` and `select` built-in commands.

Answer (score 1):

only define to RO in /etc/bashrc:

```
readonly TMOUT=900
```

it will be available in all shell levels.

Answer (score 1):

On RH/OL 9 with a security profile enabled, this setting may be automatically configured by a script:

/etc/profile.d/tmout.sh

You can change the TMOUT variable there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have export TMOUT=nnnn and readonly TMOUT lines in /etc/profile.d/timeout.sh ?

If so you should comment out the line for setting TMOUT in /etc/profile as it should be controlled in timeout.sh before it is marked readonly there.

Answer (score 0):

The default bash profile (on Ubuntu and some other distros) sources `/etc/profile`, THEN loads the user's profile (`~/.profile`). Most likely this is caused by an entry in the user's profile.

Comment out any TMOUT in your profile.

Also, this error is non-critical and you can safely ignore it if you wish.

For reference:

- Option 1: `sudo apt install bash-docs` and look in `/usr/share/docs/bash/examples/startup`
- Option 2: Check out [bash docs at gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files)